# Unable To Change Menu Bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a custom-drawn skin for an app, that eliminates the caption/title bar.  All of the menu items and system buttons are owner-drawn.  Everything works as it should, except one little bug.

When the *Maximize* button is pressed, and the window maximizes, the code should also change the button bitmap, from the "Maximize" icon, to the "Restore" icon.  Yet, I cannot get it to change.  Here is the code that handles that button command:

```
case ID_MENUBAR_MAX: {
                    WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
                    wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
                    GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &wp);
                    mII.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
                    mII.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;
                    GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, NUMMI+2, TRUE, &mII);
                    if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWNORMAL){    mII.hbmpItem = hMBB.restore;  SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0); }
                    if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED){ mII.hbmpItem = hMBB.max;      SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);  }
                    SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, NUMMI+2, TRUE, &mII);
                    DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
                    return 0;
                 }
```

As I mentioned, everything works as it should.  When the button is pressed the window maximizes or normalizes, as it should.  I just can't get the bitmap on the button to change along with it.  What am I missing?  It must be something simple.

Comment: How do you create the button(with the style `BS_ICON/BS_BITMAP`)? Try to use [`BM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-setimage) to set a button's icon/bitmap.

Comment: The question talks about a button, but the code attempts to modify a menu item. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My Bad!*  I forgot to declare `hMenu` as a *static* variable.  Because of that, I was losing my menu handle.  That's why `SetMenuItemInfo()` would not work later, in the command code blocks.  I knew that it had to be something simple.

Anyway, here are the final bits of code.  First, the creation of the Max/Restore buttons:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT   wp;
wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &wp);
if(wp.showCmd==SW_SHOWNORMAL){    mII.wID=ID_MENUBAR_MAX;      mII.hbmpItem=hMBB.max; }
if(wp.showCmd==SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED){ mII.wID=ID_MENUBAR_RESTORE;  mII.hbmpItem=hMBB.restore; }
InsertMenuItem(hMenu, NUMMI+2, TRUE, &mII);
```

Here is the handling of the commands:

```
case ID_MENUBAR_MAX:
     SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
     return 0;

case ID_MENUBAR_RESTORE:
     SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
     return 0;
```

Finally, I handled the changing of the menu button by hooking `WM_SYSCOMMAND`.  That way, the button would change, even if the command came through the system menu, or some other system command:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND: {
     auto sysResult = DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, wParam, lParam);
     if(wParam==SC_MAXIMIZE) {
         mII.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
         mII.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_BITMAP;
         mII.wID = ID_MENUBAR_RESTORE;
         mII.hbmpItem = hMBB.restore;
         SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, NUMMI+2, TRUE, &mII);
         DrawMenuBar(hWnd);
       }
      if(wParam==SC_RESTORE) {
          mII.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
          mII.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_BITMAP;
          mII.wID = ID_MENUBAR_MAX;
          mII.hbmpItem = hMBB.max;
          SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, NUMMI+2, TRUE, &mII);
          DrawMenuBar(hWnd);
        }
       return sysResult;
 }
```

Note:  It is important to call `DefWindowProc` whenever adding anything to system or non-client commands.  Use the command title for the message parameter.  The typedef `auto` is used, to handle whatever variable that the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to change the bitmap of a button instead of a menu item. You should first specify [`BS_BITMAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles)(or `BS_ICON`) when creating the button, and then send the bitmap to the button handle through the [`BM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-setimage) message, like:

```
        case ID_MENUBAR_MAX: 
        {
            WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
            wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
            HWND hMaxButton = (HWND)lParam;
            if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWNORMAL) 
            {
                SendMessage(hMaxButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hMBB.restore); 
            }
            if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED) 
            { 
                SendMessage(hMaxButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hMBB.max); 
            }

            //DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
            return 0;
        }
```

EDIT:

I have create an owner-draw menu:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        OnRightClick(hWnd);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_MEASUREITEM:
        OnMeasureItem(hWnd, (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        OnDrawItem(hWnd, (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam);
        return TRUE;
    ....
    }
}
BOOL WINAPI OnRightClick(HWND hwnd)
{
    HMENU hmenuPopup = CreatePopupMenu();
    MENUITEMINFO mii = { 0 };

    // Add the bitmap menu items to the menu. 
    MYITEM* pMyItem = (MYITEM*)malloc(sizeof(MYITEM));
    //hBitmap1&hBitmap2 have been initialized before
    pMyItem->hBitmap1 = hBitmap1;
    pMyItem->hBitmap2 = hBitmap2;

    mii.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    mii.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_DATA;
    mii.fType = MFT_OWNERDRAW;
    mii.dwItemData = (ULONG_PTR)pMyItem;
    InsertMenuItem(hmenuPopup, 0, false, &mii);
    
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rc);
    TrackPopupMenuEx(hmenuPopup,0,rc.left + 100,rc.top + 100,hwnd,0);

    free(pMyItem);

    return TRUE;
}

VOID WINAPI OnMeasureItem(HWND hwnd, LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis)
{
    //lpmis->CtlType = ODT_MENU;
    lpmis->itemWidth = 40;
    lpmis->itemHeight = 40;
}
VOID WINAPI OnDrawItem(HWND hwnd, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis)
{
    MYITEM* pMyItem = (MYITEM*)lpdis->itemData;
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    static int flag = 0;

    if (lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
    {
        flag = !flag;
    }
    if(flag)
        hBitmap = pMyItem->hBitmap1;
    else 
        hBitmap = pMyItem->hBitmap2;

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(lpdis->hDC);
    HBITMAP oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    BITMAP bitmap;
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
    BitBlt(lpdis->hDC, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}
```

When the mouse selects the menu, the bitmap of the menu will change.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above solution will not work.  The button is actually a _menu_ item.  There is no "handle".  I have searched and searched, and the results keep sending me back to `SetMenuItemInfo()`.  But, all tests show that Windows is ignoring that command.  Is it possible that `SetMenuItemInfo()` simply won't work, outside of the `WM_CREATE` block?

Comment: Try to [set with `MFT_OWNERDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#setting-the-owner-drawn-flag) for an owner-drawn menu item. You could follow the doc to handle the `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` message when you modify the owner-drawn menu item.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is simply _ignoring_ the updated information.  All of these solutions have worked in `WM_CREATE`.  But, once the window is created and running, the program simply ignores and attempted changes.  Has anyone out there successfully created an owner-drawn Min/Max button?

Comment: I can create an owner-draw menu with the doc, and could you please share the code snippet that you create that menu?