# How to find the size/position of a menu (or menu item) under Windows?

Tags: winapi

For a menu item having a cascaded sub-menu I would like to create my own (pop up) sub-menu, but for this to work I need to know where to place it. Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that yourself instead of just letting Windows do it the standard way? It has full support built in for submenus that will behave the way the user expects them to behave.

Comment: You are wildly underestimating what goes into replicating the menu implementation. If you need to customize the *appearance* (while inheriting all of the behavior), use [owner-drawn menu items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#creating-owner-drawn-menu-items).

Comment: Please check the steps in [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64314519/10611792) , to draw an owner-drawn menu item, you could set the size in [`WM_MEASUREITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-measureitem) message and draw/place it in [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem)